Javascript/CSS - First tab doesn't switch to the "inactive color" after it is selected and then another tab selected
I am new to Javascript, and am trying to incorporate it into some of my projects to practice.
Here is a screenshot of what I am working on. Its a simple tabbed section made with HTML, CSS, and a teensy bit of Javascript. Screenshot of project
The active tab is supposed to be white, and the inactive tabs are grey-blue in color. When you first open it, the first tab is white and active. The other two are the grey-blue. If I click on another tab, the first tab changes to grey-blue and the new active tab changes to white. Which is great, but––
When I click again on the first tab and then select another, the first tab remains white, even though it is no longer active. I'm unsure how to resolve it, but it is driving me mental!
Thanks in advance for any help.


function openCity(evt, cityName) {
  var i, tabcontent, tablinks;

  tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
  }

  tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
  for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }

  document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
  evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}
.tab {
    overflow: hidden;
    display:flex;
    flex-basis: 0;
}

.tab button {
    background-color: #E5ECF3;
    float: left;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    transition: 0.3s;
    flex-basis:100%
}

.active-tab{
    background-color: #fff !important;
}


.tab button:hover {
    background-color: #fff;
}

.tab button.active {
    background-color: #fff;
  
}


.logo-button{
    display: inline-flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.lbtn1, .lbtn2, .lbtn3{
    width: 100px;
}

/* Tab Content Style */
.tabcontent {
    display: none;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    background: #fff;
}

.tabcontent-active{
    display: block;
        }

.tab-child-elements{
    display: inline-flex;
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px;
    flex-flow: column wrap;
    align-items:  center;
    justify-content: center;

    p{
        text-align: center;
        width:50%
    }
}

/* Button Styles */

#logo-1{
    border-right: solid 3px #fff;
}
#logo-2{
    border: solid 0 3px 0 3px #fff;
}
#logo-3{
    border-left: solid 3px #fff;
}

.btn-1{
    background: #5AB540;
    border: 2px solid #5AB540;
}
.btn-1:hover{
    color:#5AB540;
}

.btn-2{
    background: #E9D247;
    border: 2px solid #E9D247;
}
.btn-2:hover{
    color:#E9D247;

}

.btn-3{
    background: #009BA6;
    border: 2px solid #009BA6
}
.btn-3:hover{
    color:#009BA6

}

.btn-1, .btn-2, .btn-3{
    color: #fff;
    margin-top:25px;
    border-radius: 100px;
    width: 250px;
    height: 50px;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 0 #fff;
    transition: ease-out 0.2s;
    font-weight: 600;
}

.btn-1:hover, .btn-2:hover, .btn-3:hover{
    box-shadow: inset 200px 0 0 0 #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
    transform: scale(1.02);
}

/* Mobile View */

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .lbtn1, .lbtn2, .lbtn3{
        width: 50px;
    }

    .tab-child-elements{
        p{
            width:90%;
        }
    }

}
<div class="tab-container">
    <div class="tab">
        <button class="tablinks active-tab" id="logo-1" onclick="openCity(event, 'partner1')"><img src="http://testing.kodibobo.com/wp-content/uploads/2024/10/Image-Placeholder.png" class="logo-button lbtn1"></button>
        <button class="tablinks" id="logo-2" onclick="openCity(event, 'partner2')"><img src="http://testing.kodibobo.com/wp-content/uploads/2024/10/Image-Placeholder.png" class="logo-button lbtn2"></button>
        <button class="tablinks" id="logo-3" onclick="openCity(event, 'partner3')"><img src="http://testing.kodibobo.com/wp-content/uploads/2024/10/Image-Placeholder.png" class="logo-button lbtn3"></button>
    </div>
    

    <div id="partner1" class="tabcontent tabcontent-active">
        <div class="tab-child-elements">
            A full service CRO specializing exclusively in neuromuscular disorders</p>
            <a href="" target="_blank"><button class="btn-1">LEARN MORE</button></a>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <div id="partner2" class="tabcontent">
        <div class="tab-child-elements">
            <p>a scientific, clinical, digital technology and insights platform and services company focused on accelerating health outcomes and value in drug development </p>
            <a href="" target="_blank"><button class="btn-2">LEARN MORE</button></a>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <div id="partner3" class="tabcontent">
        <div class="tab-child-elements">
            <p>the world’s largest research-focused advocacy organization with operations across 5 continents</p>
            <a href="" target="_blank"><button class="btn-3">LEARN MORE</button></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>



I tried to add the fix in the CSS by applying:
.tab button:visited {
     background-color: #E5ECF3;
 }

But this really doesn't work with all of the browser restrictions. I think it might be a Javascript solution that is beyond me.

I have a hunch that it's related to your className.replace(). I'm seeing both active and active-tab as class names. I would recommend using classList.add(), classList.remove(), or classList.toggle() which make working with css classes much easier.

Thanks! You called it. I tried it with all three to see how it reacts with each and both classList.remove() and classList.toggle() worked better than classList.replace().

For starters, you seem to be confusing the class active and active-tab.  Which one is it?
Start by changing the initial active-tab class to simply active:
<button class="tablinks active" id="logo-1" ...

Additionally, these operations are making things unnecessarily difficult:
tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
//...
evt.currentTarget.className += " active";

Use classList instead:
tablinks[i].classList.remove("active");
//...
evt.currentTarget.classList.add("active");

Putting these suggestions together:


function openCity(evt, cityName) {
  var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
  tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  
  tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
  for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].classList.remove("active");
  }

  document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
  evt.currentTarget.classList.add("active");
}
.tab {
    overflow: hidden;
    display:flex;
    flex-basis: 0;
}

.tab button {
    background-color: #E5ECF3;
    float: left;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    transition: 0.3s;
    flex-basis:100%
}

.active-tab{
    background-color: #fff !important;
}


.tab button:hover {
    background-color: #fff;
}

.tab button.active {
    background-color: #fff;
  
}


.logo-button{
    display: inline-flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.lbtn1, .lbtn2, .lbtn3{
    width: 100px;
}

/* Tab Content Style */
.tabcontent {
    display: none;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    background: #fff;
}

.tabcontent-active{
    display: block;
        }

.tab-child-elements{
    display: inline-flex;
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px;
    flex-flow: column wrap;
    align-items:  center;
    justify-content: center;

    p{
        text-align: center;
        width:50%
    }
}

/* Button Styles */

#logo-1{
    border-right: solid 3px #fff;
}
#logo-2{
    border: solid 0 3px 0 3px #fff;
}
#logo-3{
    border-left: solid 3px #fff;
}

.btn-1{
    background: #5AB540;
    border: 2px solid #5AB540;
}
.btn-1:hover{
    color:#5AB540;
}

.btn-2{
    background: #E9D247;
    border: 2px solid #E9D247;
}
.btn-2:hover{
    color:#E9D247;

}

.btn-3{
    background: #009BA6;
    border: 2px solid #009BA6
}
.btn-3:hover{
    color:#009BA6

}

.btn-1, .btn-2, .btn-3{
    color: #fff;
    margin-top:25px;
    border-radius: 100px;
    width: 250px;
    height: 50px;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 0 #fff;
    transition: ease-out 0.2s;
    font-weight: 600;
}

.btn-1:hover, .btn-2:hover, .btn-3:hover{
    box-shadow: inset 200px 0 0 0 #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
    transform: scale(1.02);
}

/* Mobile View */

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .lbtn1, .lbtn2, .lbtn3{
        width: 50px;
    }

    .tab-child-elements{
        p{
            width:90%;
        }
    }

}
<div class="tab-container">
    <div class="tab">
        <button class="tablinks active" id="logo-1" onclick="openCity(event, 'partner1')"><img src="http://testing.kodibobo.com/wp-content/uploads/2024/10/Image-Placeholder.png" class="logo-button lbtn1"></button>
        <button class="tablinks" id="logo-2" onclick="openCity(event, 'partner2')"><img src="http://testing.kodibobo.com/wp-content/uploads/2024/10/Image-Placeholder.png" class="logo-button lbtn2"></button>
        <button class="tablinks" id="logo-3" onclick="openCity(event, 'partner3')"><img src="http://testing.kodibobo.com/wp-content/uploads/2024/10/Image-Placeholder.png" class="logo-button lbtn3"></button>
    </div>
    

    <div id="partner1" class="tabcontent tabcontent-active">
        <div class="tab-child-elements">
            A full service CRO specializing exclusively in neuromuscular disorders</p>
            <a href="" target="_blank"><button class="btn-1">LEARN MORE</button></a>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <div id="partner2" class="tabcontent">
        <div class="tab-child-elements">
            <p>a scientific, clinical, digital technology and insights platform and services company focused on accelerating health outcomes and value in drug development </p>
            <a href="" target="_blank"><button class="btn-2">LEARN MORE</button></a>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <div id="partner3" class="tabcontent">
        <div class="tab-child-elements">
            <p>the world’s largest research-focused advocacy organization with operations across 5 continents</p>
            <a href="" target="_blank"><button class="btn-3">LEARN MORE</button></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>




Thank you, this was exactly the solution I needed. Much appreciated!
